# TinyMCE splits word before performing spell checks

Tags: tinymce, spell-checking

Instead of sending 'Telephone' to the server side spell checker, TinyMCE occassionally send 'Telep' and ''hone', which results in the word incorrectly flagged as misspelled.

I use a custom NHunSpell implementation at the server end, but I doubt this is the problem as when the request arrives at the server, the word has already been splitted into two, so TinyMCE must have splitted the word before sending it off.

Anyone seen this happening before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce never splits words by itself!!
Did you consider that one of your own plugins causes the splitting?
Are you using some kind of hyphenation thing? (this makes spellchecking frustrating)

Comment: Upon further investigation, I found that the word splitting behavior only occur if I make correction to a word and then initiate spell check. ie. I typed 'Teleohone', then press the left key 4 times, then backspace, then type 'p'. The word is now correctly spelt, but when I hit spell check, it sends 'Telep' and 'hone' to the server.

Comment: please edit your question and post your full tinymce configuration with a full description of what you do